# My git ignorecase is true, but i can't add to state with lower case name of file

Tags: git

I'm a new guy to git. And today I tried to add `TEXT.php` into stage, i typed `git add text.php` and no message shows, I thought it executed successfully. But when I type `git status`, it shows that `Changes not staged for commit`, and I found my `core.ignorecase` is true. So why I can't use lower name of the file?

Comment: What OS are you on? What version of git are you using? What is the output of `git check-ignore -v -- TEXT.php`?

Comment: `core.ignoreCase If true, this option enables various workarounds to enable Git to work better on filesystems that are not case sensitive, like FAT.` So I think core.ignoreCase has no effect on filesystems that are case sensitive.